# Copy Special Symbols From One PowerPoint Presentation to Another

Tags: vba, vsto, openxml, powerpoint

I need to copy text from one PowerPoint presentation to another. However, I have problems copying special symbols, such as smileys, which appear in the target presentation as empty boxes. Looking at the Open XML file in the original presentation, I can see that the `Run` containing the smiley has a "SymbolFont" attribute:

`<a:sym typeface="Wingdings" />`

However, in VBA, `Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange2.Font` =the Font of that `Run` - shows Arial.

How can I determine the SymbolFont of a text `Run` using VBA or C# (not XML)?
Then I could specify that SymbolFont in the target presentation.

Perhaps there other ways for copying the text that do not involve XML?

Note that this problem happens not only with Smileys; other special characters may show different SymbolFonts, such as:

```
<a:symTypeface = "Symbol", PitchFamily = 18, CharacterSet = 2>
```

Code example:

```
getRuns(TextRange2 paragraph)
{
    foreach(TextRange2 run in paragraph.get_Runs(-1,-1))
    _myRuns.Add(new MyRun {_text=run.Text, _font=run.Font} );
}

copyRunsToParagraph(TextRange2 paragraph)
{
    foreach(MyRun run in _myRuns)
        paragraph=paragraph.InsertAfter(run._text);
}
```

Note: `Run.Font` seems to return only the Latin font, not the Symbol font, e.g., Arial but not Wingdings. As I wrote, different symbols may have different SymbolFonts, so always using Wingdings does not work.

Comment: What's the code that you use to copy the text?

Comment: I don't think so - hard to believe it cannot be done.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Any solutions yet?

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done in VBA.